# Perl Devel::StackTrace reverse order of frames

Tags: perl

I am trying to use the Perl module [Devel::StackTrace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::StackTrace) to display errors with stack trace, the frames are showed bottom to top of the source of the error, is there a way to reverse this order to display the error source frame at the top because this is the first thing you need to know then follow tracing if needed to the bottom.

Below is the test code to reproduce the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe

BEGIN {
    $|=1;
    use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser set_message);
    use Devel::StackTrace;
    use Devel::StackTrace::AsHTML;
    use PadWalker;
    use Devel::StackTrace::WithLexicals;
    sub handle_errors {
        my $msg = shift;
        #my $trace = Devel::StackTrace->new(indent => 1, message => $msg);
        my $trace = Devel::StackTrace::WithLexicals->new(indent => 1, message => $msg);
        #print $trace->as_html;
        print $trace->as_string;
    }
    set_message(\&handle_errors);
}

show_error();

exit;
```

Below is the text format error message:

```
Undefined subroutine &amp;main::show_error called at C:/apache/htdocs/tests/test.cgi line 24.
     at C:\apache\htdocs\tests\test.cgi line 17
        main::handle_errors('Undefined subroutine &amp;main::show_error called at C:/apache/htdocs/tests/test.cgi line 24.^J') called at C:\perl\site\lib\CGI\Carp.pm line 525
        eval {...} at C:\perl\site\lib\CGI\Carp.pm line 524
        CGI::Carp::fatalsToBrowser('Undefined subroutine &main::show_error called at C:/apache/htdocs/tests/test.cgi line 24.^J') called at C:\perl\site\lib\CGI\Carp.pm line 444
        CGI::Carp::die('Undefined subroutine &main::show_error called at C:/apache/htdocs/tests/test.cgi line 24.^J') called at C:\apache\htdocs\tests\test.cgi line 24
```

Comment: You're *already* showing stack frames from top to bottom (the most recent frame goes on the top of the stack). From the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::StackTrace#trace-as_string-p): "`$trace->as_string(\%p)` Calls `$frame->as_string()` on each frame from top to bottom..."

Comment: Then what I want is the reverse anyway.

Comment: How would reversing the stack trace help you debug? If an error occurs in function `foo` that's where you should look, not in some function at the bottom of the stack.

Comment: if you see the traces, the last one `called at C:\apache\htdocs\tests\test.cgi line 24` is the source of the problem, this should be at the top of the traces.

Comment: So you want the last thing to execute at the top? That's what you have. If the call to `show_error();` was ten levels deep, those tens levels would appear below the line with the call to `show_error()`

Comment: @ ikegami all I want in very short is to reverse the order it is showing now, I think this should be an option in `Devel::StackTrace` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the module `Devel::StackTrace` source code, I was able to answer my question.
The module has the method `frames` where it returns or sets the frames. So I reversed the order simply by this line before calling the `as_string` or `as_html` methods:

```
$trace->frames(reverse $trace->frames);
```

Here is the modified code with the solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe

BEGIN {
    $|=1;
    use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser set_message);
    use Devel::StackTrace;
    use Devel::StackTrace::AsHTML;
    use PadWalker;
    use Devel::StackTrace::WithLexicals;
    sub handle_errors {
        my $msg = shift;
        my $trace = Devel::StackTrace->new(indent => 1, message => "$msg\n");
        #my $trace = Devel::StackTrace::WithLexicals->new(indent => 1, message => $msg);
        $trace->frames(reverse $trace->frames);
        #print $trace->as_html;
        print $trace->as_string;
    }
    set_message(\&handle_errors);
}

show_error();

exit;
```

It does exactly what I want.